# laravel raw query date comparisons

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a string columns `ddate = ('2020-06-02')` and `time_start = ('4:25 PM')` which I want to compare to `date('Y-m-d H:i A')`.

Say that `date('Y-m-d H:i A')` = `2021-06-02 01:14 AM`...
What I want is to show all rows where `ddate`+`time_start` > `date('Y-m-d H:I A')`

my where clause is:

```
->whereRaw('CONCAT(event_date, " ", time_start) > DATE("Y-m-d H:i A")')
```

but the result still shows all the date below '2021-06-02 01:14 AM'

I also tried

```
->whereRaw('DATE("Y-m-d H:i", CONCAT(event_date, " ", time_start)) > DATE("Y-m-d H:i")')
```

but I got syntax error.

is my second query already correct but just wrong syntax?

If not, how do I achieve what I wanted?

Comment: First convert your both dates in same format and then you can compare them. Try using date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing the current date using php, you must do this way:

```
->whereRaw('CONCAT(event_date, " ", time_start) >'. date("Y-m-d H:i A"))
```

and if you want mysql to handle current date use now()

```
->whereRaw('CONCAT(event_date, " ", time_start) > now()')
```

Comment: the second one did it for me.
I just noticed that if you enclosed the `now()` inside the string, it becomes `now()` from `mysql` while concatenating '....' . now() is Carbon

Answer (score 1):

MySQL DATE() function is used to extract the date part from the datetime. Use PHP date function instead or you can use Carbon.

```
->whereRaw("CONCAT(event_date, ' ', time_start) > " . date('Y-m-d g:i A'))
```